# Is $x^TAx=\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda xx^T)$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Where the matrix $A$ has an eigendecomposition $A=U\Lambda U^T$. I am asking because I have seen that $x^TAx=\mathrm{tr}(Ax x^T)$ which seems to imply $x^TAx=\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda xx^T)$.

In particular: $x^TAx= \mathrm{tr}(Axx^T)=\mathrm{tr}(U\Lambda U^T xx^T)=\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda UU^T xx^T)=\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda xx^T) $

This seems like a contradiction, where am I wrong?

Comment: This is the most common mistake about the trace formula: $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ does not imply that the trace of a product is invariant under arbitrary permutations of the factors. The formula does imply that $tr(ABC) = tr(BCA) = tr(CAB)$, but generally $tr(ABC) \not= tr(BAC)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm{tr}(U\Lambda U^T xx^T)$ is generally not equal to $\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda UU^T xx^T)$ since the trace only allows for cyclic reordering.